# Is my Ghusl valid, if I didn’t know?

Tags: salat, ghusl, hanafi

A few days ago I made my ghusl and normally went on with my day and prayed. Just now, I took a close look at my nails and noticed that there was a bit of glue, that must have been there from the last time I used glue ( before I made ghusl ).
I wonder if that makes my Ghusl invalid, as the whole body has to be wetted for ghusl, but I didn‘t know about the glue until now.

Answer (score 0):

If the barrier is smaller than the size of a lentil, there is no problem, and the Ghusl is valid. If it is invalid, the prayers should be repeated as Qada prayer.

[Reference](https://www.eporsesh.com/content/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%86%D8%B3%D8%A8-%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%86%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%BA%D8%B3%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%86%D9%87%D8%9F)